# Visual Studio 2015 MSTest cannot run a loadtest

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest, load-testing, msloadtest

I am trying to run a batch file that contains the MSTest running a load test file but it always returns an error message of **"Visual Studio Enterprise is required to execute the test."** Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise is already installed in my machine together with MSTest.

Here are the contents of the batch file:

```
pushd ..
"D:\Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:%arg1% /testsettings:Local.Testsettings /resultsfile:Scripts\TestResults\%arg2%.trx"
popd
```

Where:

**%arg1%** = loadtest.loadtest

**%arg2%** = loadtest.loadtest.date

Local.Testsettings: **x64**

Comment: Some parts of Visual Studio only install into or work from the system drive which is normally `C:`. Your batch file runs `D:...MStest.exe`. Do you have multiple Visual Studio versions installed and any of them on non-system drives?

Comment: run your batch file from the developer command prompt

Answer (score 0):

As part of my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162638/mstest-run-loadtests-and-write-results-to-sql-server-database/53211350#53211350) I had the same issue when trying to run my tests through TFS/Powershell. To fix it, I took @allen's advise to call the "Developer Command Prompt" before running the tests and implemented a solution in a Powershell script, seems to work for the two servers I've tested it on, I've adapted it to be BAT compatible:

**Note: This is for VS 2017, I believe you simply change the year in the path to invoke a previous version*

*(For @user6329531, BAT version of the fix, call this before you execute the tests)*

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

*(My full Powershell script for running Microsoft "LoadTests")*

```
param (
    [string]$path = ""
 )

#For this to work correctly you need to make sure the following things are done: 
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/53211350/2912011
Write-Output $path

#Start deveng, for some reason it likes to complain if it's not runnning
#https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1d5574c0-4a56-4dd1-b390-3a3683278d16/loadtest-require-visual-studio-enterprise?forum=vstest
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

#Run the "Developer Command Prompt" 
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\"
./VsDevCmd.bat

#Navigate to the MSTest directory
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\"

#Iterate through the entire directory, run each loadtest one at a time
$fullPath = $path

Get-ChildItem $fullPath -Filter *.loadtest | 
Foreach-Object {
    $content = $_.FullName

    Write-Output $content

    ./mstest.exe /testcontainer:"$content" /detail:testtype
}

try {
    Get-Process devenv -IncludeUserName | Where UserName -match EBMTFSServiceAccount| Stop-Process
}
catch {
    #This may fail, if so it probably is not an issue, but we need to double check...
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
}
```